Generating a tax record from trade history
I have a trade history table that looks like this:
CREATE TABLE trade (
    trade_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    stock_id INT NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    sell BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    shares INT NOT NULL,
    usd_total DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL
);

I want to query my trade record for a tax report. Something that result in



stock_id
buy_date
sell_date
shares
buy_usd_total
sell_usd_total













meaning each sell trade would be matched with one or more rows, each time "spending" shares from the buy rows then moving on to the next.
For example trades of



trade_id
stock_id
date
sell
shares
usd_total




1
1
2021-01-01
0
2
100.00


2
1
2021-01-02
0
2
120.00


3
1
2021-01-03
1
3
300.00


4
1
2021-01-04
1
1
150.00



should result in



stock_id
buy_date
sell_date
shares
buy_usd_total
sell_usd_total




1
2021-01-01
2021-01-03
2
100.00
200.00


1
2021-01-02
2021-01-03
1
60.00
100.00


1
2021-01-02
2021-01-04
1
60.00
150.00



Is this something that's possible with SQL? I've tried to wrap my head around it, but keeping score of the remaining shares of buys and sells is difficult. Should I push forward or go with an iterative approach in python?

What is the grouping/matching logic of your result?

looks like a LAG windowed function

You can enumerate individual share purchase/sale events and self-join to match the 1st purchase to the 1st sale, 2nd purchase to the 2nd sale and so on: demo at db<>fiddle
with atomic_operation as (
  select*,usd_total/shares as usd
         ,count(*)over(partition by stock_id,sell 
                       order by date,n) as nth_operation
  from trade cross join lateral generate_series(1,shares)as g(n) )
select purchase.stock_id
      ,purchase.date     as buy_date
      ,sale.date         as sell_date
      ,count(*)          as shares
      ,sum(purchase.usd) as buy_usd_total
      ,sum(sale.usd)     as sell_usd_total
from atomic_operation as purchase
join atomic_operation as sale
using(nth_operation,stock_id)
where purchase.sell is false
  and sale.sell is true
group by 1,2,3
order by 1,2,3;




stock_id
buy_date
sell_date
shares
buy_usd_total
sell_usd_total




1
2021-01-01
2021-01-03
2
100.0
200.0


1
2021-01-02
2021-01-03
1
60.0
100.0


1
2021-01-02
2021-01-04
1
60.0
150.0




count(*)over w1 uses the window (partition by stock_id,sell order by date,n). It'll keep a separate running/stepping/tumbling count for each stock_id, also separating sales from purchases, following the buy/sell event date.
cross join lateral generate_series(1,shares) clones each trade row as many times as there were shares in the event, to produce a separate sale/purchase row for each individual share. The usd_total/shares establishes their per-share price.
Aggregate functions compact the list of individually matched events into groups, as per your example.


Clean and simple code, but when I test this using different data it seems to fall apart. because it creates additional ghost sales.  example: add an additional buy/sell for a different stock id on a different date.

@wct097 You're welcome to attach a fiddle demonstrating what, when and where falls apart and I'll take a look.

here you go, using your answer: https://dbfiddle.uk/rZfpbddV
and what I believe is the correct result using my much more verbose and less elegant answer: https://dbfiddle.uk/I7-8vTr3

@wct097 Good point, I remember moving around the join conditions and I must've lost the stock_id, only 1 of which was in the test sample. I didn't read into what you altered in the set but you can verify this demo with the missing condition re-added. I'll try to take a look at your recursive CTE later - with large share counts multiplying rows is doomed to perform worse than something that actually works without swelling the set.

not sure how I missed the missing stock_id in your join. I was focused on the lateral cross join in your CTE which I was unfamiliar with (the lateral operator) and skipped over that.  You're right, that fixes the problem and is much more elegant and probably more performant than my solution.

@wct097 It's good to have a peer review. Thanks for taking not just a look, but a deep dive with a cross-check. Still, it's pretty likely you can come up with a pl/pgsql or a plain SQL recursive CTE approach that outperforms this simply by not having to multiply the set. It might be longer and/or less readable, but at some point the performance gain more than justifies that.

always enjoy digging into interesting topics.  I have a couple things I'd like to test in both of our answers to compare/contrast/validate.

@wct097 Here's a performance test. To make it apples-to-apples I swapped the left for an inner join in yours and commented out the order by in mine. Given the same assumptions (one trade per stock_id per date, no sales exceeding sum of prior purchases) they get the same results - easier to compare on smaller samples but in the larger one you can still see the same final row count of 16815. Performance wise, they are comparable, at least in this sample size range. d r's seems to attempt taking a similar approach you did but runs out of time and memory.

Here's the one running out of memory

My answer is going to be much more verbose than the answer by Zegarek but I believe it works correctly with data beyond the sample dataset.  I use recursion in the initial CTE to break out the individual shares for each transaction then aggregate them in terms of buys and sells so I can match them back up per-share to get not only the requested output, but also things like days held and gain/loss.
Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/I7-8vTr3
with recursive shares as (
    -- get each transaction, break out cost per share, and create a first row for the first of X shares in the transaction
    select 
          trade_id
        , stock_id
        , date
        , sell
        , shares        
        , usd_total
        , usd_total / shares as price_per_share
        , 1 as share_number 
    from trade

    union all

    -- recursively break out an additional row for each share of the transaction
    select 
          t.trade_id
        , t.stock_id
        , t.date
        , t.sell
        , t.shares
        , t.usd_total
        , t.usd_total / t.shares as price_per_share
        , 1 + s.share_number as share_number 
    from trade t
    inner join shares s
      on s.trade_id = t.trade_id
     and s.share_number < t.shares
), bought_shares as (
    -- get all of the individual shares bought and sequence them in order they were bought
    select 
          trade_id
        , stock_id
        , date
        , price_per_share
        , share_number
        , row_number() over (partition by stock_id, sell order by date, trade_id) as buy_seq
    from shares
    where sell = False
), sold_shares as (
    -- get all of the individual shares sold and sequence them in order they were sold
    select 
          trade_id
        , stock_id
        , date
        , price_per_share
        , share_number
        , row_number() over (partition by stock_id, sell order by date, trade_id) as sell_seq
    from shares
    where sell = True
), sale_details as (
    -- now we match sold shares to the purchased shares to report on sales using FIFO logic on a per-share basis
    select 
          s.stock_id
        , b.date as buy_date
        , s.date as sell_date
        , coalesce(cast(s.date - b.date as varchar), 'Unknown') as days_held -- handles bad data with an unmatched sell
        , s.price_per_share - b.price_per_share as gain_or_loss
        , b.price_per_share as buy_usd_per_share
        , s.price_per_share as sell_usd_per_share
    from sold_shares s
    left join bought_shares b -- inner join if you don't want to deal with data including a sale without a buy
      on b.stock_id = s.stock_id
     and b.buy_seq = s.sell_seq
)
select 
      stock_id
    , buy_date
    , sell_date
    --, max(days_held) as days_held
    , count(*) as shares
    , cast(sum(buy_usd_per_share) as decimal(18,2)) as buy_usd_total
    , cast(sum(sell_usd_per_share)     as decimal(18,2)) as sell_usd_total
    --, sum(gain_or_loss) as gain_or_loss
from sale_details
group by
    stock_id
    , buy_date
    , sell_date;

The result set is the same as Zegarek's:


Using recursive cte to collect buy and sell data per share in the same row and then do the data preparation and calculating buy_shares_balance in another cte (named it grid) to do the final job using Case expressions on buy_shares_balance  column.
Here is the complete code:
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table 
  trade ( trade_id INT PRIMARY KEY, stock_id INT NOT NULL, date DATE NOT NULL,
          sell BOOLEAN NOT NULL, shares INT NOT NULL, usd_total DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL
        );
Insert Into trade 
  VALUES (1,1,'2021-01-01',false,2,100.00), (2,1,'2021-01-02',false,2,120.00), 
         (3,1,'2021-01-03',true,3,300.00),  (4,1,'2021-01-04',true,1,150.00) returning *;

... recursive cte (buys) collecting all the buy and sell data in the same row per share (resultset in the fiddle down under the code)
WITH
  recursive buys ( buy_trade_id, stock_id, buy_date, buy_shares, buy_usd_total, 
                   share_num, buy_usd, sell_trade_id, sell_date, sell_shares, sell_usd_total ) AS
      ( Select trade_id, stock_id, date, shares, usd_total, 
               1, usd_total / shares, 0::int, Null::date, 0::int, 0::decimal
        From   trade
        Where  NOT sell 
      UNION ALL
        Select   b.buy_trade_id, b.stock_id, b.buy_date, b.buy_shares, b.buy_usd_total, 
                 b.share_num + 1, b.buy_usd, t.trade_id, t.date, t.shares, t.usd_total
        From     buys b
        Inner Join trade t ON( t.stock_id = b.stock_id And t.sell )
        Where    share_num < buy_shares
      ), 

... another cte preparing the data and calculating buy_shares_balance (resultset in the fiddle down under the code)
  grid as
    ( Select    stock_id, 
                buy_trade_id, sell_trade_id,
                buy_date, sell_date, 
                buy_shares, sell_shares, 
                buy_usd, sell_usd_total / sell_shares as sell_usd,
                buy_usd_total, sell_usd_total,
          --
               buy_shares - 
               Sum(  Case When (sell_usd_total / sell_shares) / buy_usd >= buy_shares  
                         Then (sell_usd_total / sell_shares) / buy_usd
                     End 
                  ) Over(Partition By sell_trade_id, buy_date, buy_shares, buy_usd
                         Order By sell_trade_id, buy_date, buy_shares, buy_usd
                         Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as buy_shares_balance
      From      buys
      Where     sell_trade_id > 0
      Order By  sell_date, buy_date
    )

--    M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT   stock_id, buy_date, sell_date, shares, 
         Round(buy_usd_total, 2) as buy_usd_total, 
         Round(Case When sell_usd_total >= sell_usd 
                    Then sell_usd_total 
               Else sell_usd 
               End, 2) as sell_usd_total
FROM   ( Select  stock_id, buy_date, sell_date, sell_usd, 
                 --
                 Case When buy_shares_balance = 0
                      Then buy_shares 
                      When buy_shares_balance Is Null
                      Then 1
                      When buy_shares_balance < 0 And buy_shares_balance > -1
                      Then 1
                End  as shares, 
                 --
                 Case When buy_shares_balance = 0
                      Then buy_usd_total 
                      When buy_shares_balance Is Null
                      Then buy_usd
                      When buy_shares_balance < 0 And buy_shares_balance > -1
                      Then buy_usd
                End as buy_usd_total,
                --
                Case When buy_shares_balance = 0
                      Then sell_usd_total - sell_usd 
                      When buy_shares_balance Is Null
                      Then sell_usd_total - 
                           ( Count(Case When Coalesce(buy_shares_balance, 0) = 0 Then 1 End) 
                               Over(Partition By sell_trade_id Order By buy_trade_id
                                    Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) *
                             sell_usd )
                      When buy_shares_balance < 0 And buy_shares_balance > -1
                      Then sell_usd_total
                End as sell_usd_total
         From    grid
       )
WHERE   sell_usd_total Is Not Null And sell_usd_total >= 0

/*      R e s u l t :
stock_id    buy_date    sell_date   shares  buy_usd_total   sell_usd_total
--------    ----------  ----------  ------  -------------   --------------
       1    2021-01-01  2021-01-03       2         100.00           200.00
       1    2021-01-02  2021-01-03       1          60.00           100.00
       1    2021-01-02  2021-01-04       1          60.00           150.00   */

See the step by step fiddle here.
